# jQuery Confirm (external plugin) not working properly

Tags: jquery, plugins, confirm

I've been having a very bizarre issue with the jQuery Confirm code on my website. I've been using a plugin designed by Nadia Alramli (http://nadiana.com/jquery-confirm-plugin)

This plugin stops the action of the element it is applied to, and provides a confirmation dialog first. I use this for "action buttons" on a funds application management system that I've developed. Everything was working fine until recently, when literally, out of the blue, the code just **stopped working**. The confirm dialog shows, but when you click "yes," the button's action doesn't execute.

I've checked and re-checked the code, and nothing has been changed from the way it was originally implemented. I've also created an example page where I've removed all other unnecessary code, and I'm still having the same problem.
Here's a link to my example page:
http://www.greeleyw2w.org/admin/example2.html

What could cause something like this? The only things I can think of are either a problem with my web host (GoDaddy), or something with the Google hosted version of jQuery.

```
//Actions for the status change buttons
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#test").click(function(){ //The action of the button
    alert("You confirmed the button click.");
});

$('.confirm').confirm({ //Captures button action, asks for confirmation.
    msg:'Are you sure?',
    wrapper:'<span style="color:#099"></span>',
    dialogShow:'fadeIn',
    dialogSpeed:'slow',
    buttons: {
        wrapper:'<button></button>',
        separator:'  '
    }
});
});
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's incompatible with JQuery 1.8.

Around line 43, change the code from:

var events = jQuery.data(target, 'events');

to

var events = jQuery._data(target, "events");

The event model broke with 1.8 due to a removed api.

http://blog.jquery.com/2012/08/09/jquery-1-8-release

Comment: Works for me.  I found I had to change '.data' to '._data' on lines 45 and 49.

Answer (score 0):

try to change your code from

```
$('.confirm').confirm({
   ....
});
```

to

```
$('#test').confirm({
   ....
});
```

Comment: I've actually tried that already. I had confirm defined as a class so it could be used on multiple buttons. This setup was working fine before.

Comment: @bnrup, it works [here](http://jsfiddle.net/qT9HH/1/) , I think the problems is jQuery library which you use it. I have tried in [JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qT9HH/1/) using jQery 1.7.2 and it worked, but when I change it using [jQuery 1.8.2](http://jsfiddle.net/qT9HH/2/), it doesnt work.

So, try to use another library of your jquery. It should work.

Answer (score 0):

I think you miss an ID on your "Yes" button.
Here your code:

```
<span style="color: rgb(0, 153, 153); display: none;">
Are you sure?
<button>Yes</button>
<button>No</button>
</span>
<input id="test" class="confirm" type="button" style="display: inline;" value="Test Confirm Function" />
```

so change your HTML code by add ID attribute to Yes Button. Look at revised code bellow:

```
<span style="color: rgb(0, 153, 153); display: none;">
Are you sure?
<button id="test">Yes</button>
<button>No</button>
</span>
<input class="confirm" type="button" style="display: inline;" value="Test Confirm Function" />
```

Or you can change your javascript action section to become:

```
$('button').click(function(){
  alert("You confirmed the button click."); 
});
```

Look at on [plugin documentation](http://nadiana.com/jquery-confirm-plugin) on "Second Example", it similar to your case.

Comment: The code you're speaking of is automatically generated by the plugin. Therefore, it shouldn't be a problem.

Comment: then you must change your javascript action section. look at edited answer

Comment: Your edited answer would simply apply the action to all buttons, which I definitely don't want to do.

Comment: Right. So, to be clear, please add pieces of your code in your question.

Comment: The plugin is designed to capture the event that is applied to the button, and re-assign it to the yes button that is generated. I've also added my code to the OP.

Answer (score 0):

on jquery confirm replace the code with this:

```
/**
 * Confirm plugin 1.3
 *
 * Copyright (c) 2007 Nadia Alramli (http://nadiana.com/)
 * Dual licensed under the MIT (MIT-LICENSE.txt)
 * and GPL (GPL-LICENSE.txt) licenses.
 */

/**
 * For more docs and examples visit:
 * http://nadiana.com/jquery-confirm-plugin
 * For comments, suggestions or bug reporting,
 * email me at: http://nadiana.com/contact/
 */

jQuery.fn.confirm = function(options) {
  options = jQuery.extend({
    msg: 'Are you sure?',
    stopAfter: 'never',
    wrapper: '<span></span>',
    eventType: 'click',
    dialogShow: 'show',
    dialogSpeed: '',
    timeout: 0
  }, options);
  options.stopAfter = options.stopAfter.toLowerCase();
  if (!options.stopAfter in ['never', 'once', 'ok', 'cancel']) {
    options.stopAfter = 'never';
  }
  options.buttons = jQuery.extend({
    ok: 'Yes',
    cancel: 'No',
    wrapper:'<a href="#"></a>',
    separator: '/'
  }, options.buttons);

  // Shortcut to eventType.
  var type = options.eventType;

  return this.each(function() {
    var target = this;
    var $target = jQuery(target);
    var timer;
    var saveHandlers = function() {
      var events = jQuery.data(target, 'events');
      if (!events && target.href) {
        // No handlers but we have href
        $target.bind('click', function() {document.location = target.href});
        events = jQuery.data(target, 'events');
      } else if (!events) {
        // There are no handlers to save.
        return;
      }
      target._handlers = new Array();
      for (var i in events[type]) {
        target._handlers.push(events[type][i]);
      }
    }

    // Create ok button, and bind in to a click handler.
    var $ok = jQuery(options.buttons.wrapper)
      .append(options.buttons.ok)
      .click(function() {
      // Check if timeout is set.
      if (options.timeout != 0) {
        clearTimeout(timer);
      }
      $target.unbind(type, handler);
      $target.show();
      $dialog.hide();
      // Rebind the saved handlers.
      if (target._handlers != undefined) {
        jQuery.each(target._handlers, function() {
          $target.click(this.handler);
        });
      }
      // Trigger click event.
      $target.click();
      if (options.stopAfter != 'ok' && options.stopAfter != 'once') {
        $target.unbind(type);
        // Rebind the confirmation handler.
        $target.one(type, handler);
      }
      alert("You confirmed the button click.");
      return false;
    })

    var $cancel = jQuery(options.buttons.wrapper).append(options.buttons.cancel).click(function() {
      // Check if timeout is set.
      if (options.timeout != 0) {
        clearTimeout(timer);
      }
      if (options.stopAfter != 'cancel' && options.stopAfter != 'once') {
        $target.one(type, handler);
      }
      $target.show();
      $dialog.hide();
      return false;
    });

    if (options.buttons.cls) {
      $ok.addClass(options.buttons.cls);
      $cancel.addClass(options.buttons.cls);
    }

    var $dialog = jQuery(options.wrapper)
    .append(options.msg)
    .append($ok)
    .append(options.buttons.separator)
    .append($cancel);

    var handler = function() {
      jQuery(this).hide();

      // Do this check because of a jQuery bug
      if (options.dialogShow != 'show') {
        $dialog.hide();
      }

      $dialog.insertBefore(this);
      // Display the dialog.
      $dialog[options.dialogShow](options.dialogSpeed);
      if (options.timeout != 0) {
        // Set timeout
        clearTimeout(timer);
        timer = setTimeout(function() {$cancel.click(); $target.one(type, handler);}, options.timeout);
      }
      return false;
    };

    saveHandlers();
    $target.unbind(type);
    target._confirm = handler
    target._confirmEvent = type;
    $target.one(type, handler);
  });
}
```

Comment: The plugin is supposed to _automatically_ obtain the button action. It's not supposed to be hard-coded.

Comment: you just have to put event in yes button, in that case of that plugin, add alert when $target.click = yes

Comment: There's not a problem with the plugin code, as it works just fine on the demo site. There's something on _my_ site that's preventing it from working. That's what this question was about.